# Pushing to remote branch

Tags: git

I have a git problem/question.

We are using bitbucket as our remote repo. Until now we've only had the master branch.

The other person I'm working on this with created a "develop" branch now the project is live for us to continue working on.

I've been working locally and have made changes and commited them.

I now want to push these to the remote "develop" branch.

I thought that

```
git push origin develop
```

would do it but i get

```
error: src refspec develop does not match any.
```

What does this mean?. I can see that the develop branch does indeed exist so what am I doing wrong?

Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for your answers, I've got things working again.

For anyone interested this is how I did it.

I did a

```
git pull origin master
```

and that updated my local repo and it was now aware there was a remote develop branch

I then did

```
git checkout develop
```

to switch to my local develop branch.. then

```
git merge master
```

to merge all the changes I had done in master into the develop branch
Then doing

```
git push origin develop
```

worked fine.

Now all my changes are safe in the develop branch I can revert the master branch (where I was working) so it's the same as the remote master branch and everything is as it should be.

Not sure If that was the easiest way to go about it but I learned a lot about git.

Thanks again for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

`develop` exist in where?  local? remote? or both?  Try:

```
git push origin HEAD:develop
```

Comment: develop only exists on remote. I'm working locally on master branch... i guess this is the problem. I tried to do HEAD:develop and got this...

Comment: error: failed to push some refs to 'https://mark_stewart@bitbucket.org/mark_stewart/museum-poisoners.git'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.  See the
'Note about fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.

Comment: This is a `non-fast-forward` update. That is: some change in the remote repos is not in local. You should pull them in before pushing.

Comment: Or if you're confident it's safe to overwrite the remote `develop` changes, you can `git push -f`.

Answer (score 1):

If you use

```
git push <repo> <src>
```

eg,
    git push origin develop

then git expects to find a local branch called 'develop' that it can take to push to a remote branch of the same name. Since there is no local branch of that name you get the error.

So, if you want to push to a new (or existing) remote branch that has a different name locally then you would do the following:

```
git push <repo> <src>:<dst>
```

eg,

```
git push origin master:develop
```

That should work. *checks*. It does.

Answer (score 1):

Did you forget to commit your work? This happens when you clone an empty repo, add files but forget to commit them before pushing.

Answer (score 0):

You have not yet pulled develop from the server. You have a remote develop branch, but you do not have a local develop tracking branch.

```
git checkout develop
```

This will create the local develop tracking branch.

If you already committed your changes, those changes are on the master branch that you were using before. Moving those changes to the develop branch is a bit more complicated.

Moving those changes can be explained once we've identified the problem that you are actually having.